# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string must not have replace block

Tags: path, get, retrofit2, illegalargumentexception

I am using Retrofit and GET Request:

```
@GET("Master/GetConsignerPartyList?prefix={claimId}")
    Observable<ConsignerPartyResponse> consignerPartyReq(@HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, @Path("claimId") String search);
```

and getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "prefix={claimId}" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ?prefix={claimId} from your url because query name should not be static in url.

```
@GET("Master/GetConsignerPartyList")
Observable<ConsignerPartyResponse> consignerPartyReq(
              @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers,
              @Query("prefix") String search);
```

It's will work :-)

Comment: Brother, My url will be  after add prefix like : ABB >>> @GET("Master/GetConsignerPartyList?prefix=ABB")

Comment: do you tried my solution?

Comment: yes , right now i used it but its give me whole search list, filtering not working after 
 add prefix, but now error is gone

Comment: do you passed value for `search` in method?

Comment: yes, i did it, my default URL is "Master/GetConsignerPartyList?prefix="

Comment: you are not passing `ABB` in `consignerPartyReq()` that's why it's returns whole list. can you add your api call place?

Comment: sorry bro, it was my fault... you are right.. its work..thank you very much

Comment: okay if it's working for you mark answer as accepted and upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1):

`claimId` is part of the query as you've set it in the URL - `?prefix={claimId}"`

`@Path` replaces placeholders in the path, i.e., `@GET("Master/{claimId}/")`.

To replace in the query just use `@Query("claimId")`:

```
@GET("Master/GetConsignerPartyList?prefix={claimId}")
Observable<ConsignerPartyResponse> consignerPartyReq(
    @HeaderMap Map<String, String> headers, 
    @Query("claimId") String search);
```